# Differentiation of dependent variable as integrand by just one independent variable

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

$$-{\partial{H}_{y}\over\partial\mathrm{z}}=\epsilon{\partial{E}_{x}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}~~~,~~~{\partial{E}_{x}\over\partial\mathrm{z}}=-\mu{\partial{H}_{y}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\tag{1}$$

$${\partial{H}_{x}\over\partial\mathrm{z}}=\epsilon{\partial{E}_{y}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}~~~,~~~{\partial{E}_{y}\over\partial\mathrm{z}}=\mu{\partial{H}_{x}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\tag{2}$$

$$f_{1},g_{1}~~\leftarrow\text{arbitrary functions}\tag{3}$$

$$v=\sqrt{{1\over\epsilon\mu}}\tag{4}$$

$$E_{x}=f_1(z-vt)~~~,~~~E_{y}=g_1(z-vt)\tag{5}$$

I've been unable to derive the following from substituting and integrating with$~z~$.

$$\color{green}{H_x=-\sqrt{{\epsilon\over\mu}}g_1(z-vt)=-\sqrt{{\epsilon\over\mu}}E_{y}~~~,~~~H_y=\sqrt{{\epsilon\over\mu}}f_1(z-vt)=\sqrt{{\epsilon\over\mu}}E_x}\tag{6}$$

$$\int{\partial H_x\over\partial\mathrm{z}}\,\partial\mathrm{z}=\epsilon\int{\partial E_y\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\,\partial\mathrm{z}\tag{7}$$

$$H_x=\epsilon\int{\partial E_y\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\,{\partial\mathrm{t}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\,\partial\mathrm{z}\tag{8}$$

$$=\epsilon\int{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\left(E_{y}\right)\partial\mathrm{t}\,{\partial\mathrm{z}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\tag{9}$$

$$=\epsilon\int\,{\partial\mathrm{z}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\cdot{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\left(E_{y}\right)\partial\mathrm{t}\,\tag{10}$$

$${\partial\mathrm{z}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}~~\leftarrow~~\text{How can I handle this?}\tag{11}$$

Even I don't know whether that green equation be obtained in this way.

**ADD**

$$\underbrace{{\partial E_y\over\partial\mathrm{z}}={\partial\over\partial\mathrm{z}}g_1(z-vt)=\mu{\partial H_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}}_{\text{Equations which already given}}\tag{12}$$

As integrations are applied to the right 2 terms,

$$\int{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{z}}g_1(z-vt)\,\partial\mathrm{z}=\mu\int{\partial H_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\,\partial\mathrm{z}\tag{13}$$

$$g_1(z-vt)=\mu\underbrace{\int{\partial H_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\,\partial\mathrm{z}}_{\text{Confusing}}\tag{14}$$

As with the left 2 terms.

$${\partial H_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}={1\over\mu}{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{z}}g_1(z-vt)\tag{15}$$

$$\int{\partial H_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\,\partial\mathrm{t}={1\over\mu}\int{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{z}}g_1(z-vt)\,\partial\mathrm{t}\tag{16}$$

$$H_{x}={1\over\mu}\underbrace{\int{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{z}}g_1(z-vt)\,\partial\mathrm{t}}_{\text{I can't proceed from here}}\tag{17}$$

Comment: Hint : To see that the green equation holds just verify that for $E_y=g_1(z-vt)$ and 
$H_x=-\frac{1}{\mu v}g_1(z-vt)=-\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}}g_1(z-vt),$
$$
\frac{\partial E_y}{\partial z}=g_1'(z-vt)=\mu\frac{\partial H_x}{\partial t}\,.
$$
And so on.

Comment: Still I am confused...X0

Comment: Why exactly ? I cannot read your mind .

Comment: I've added my thoughts on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration is normally written with $dz$ and $dt$ instead of $\partial z$ and $\partial t$. You can in general not say much about $\int\partial_z g(z,t)\,dt$. But in your case
$$
\int{\partial\over\partial z}g_1(z-vt)dt=\int g'_1(z-vt)\,dt
$$
which happens to equal
$$
-\frac{1}{v}\int{\partial\over\partial t}g_1(z-vt)dt=\frac{1}{v} g_1(z-vt).
$$

Comment: I think I've finally got what you've written. 
$$
\begin{align}
A&:=\int{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{z}}g_1(z-vt)\mathrm{dt}\\
u&:=z-vt\\
{\partial\mathrm{u}\over\partial\mathrm{z}}&=1\iff\partial\mathrm{u}=\partial\mathrm{z}\\
{\partial\mathrm{u}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}&=-v\iff\partial\mathrm{t}=\mathrm{dt}=-{1\over v}\partial\mathrm{u}\\
A&=\int{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{u}}g_1(u)\left(-{1\over v}\right)\partial\mathrm{u}\\
&=-{1\over v}\int{\partial\over\partial\mathrm{u}}g_1(u)\partial\mathrm{u}
\\&=-{1\over v}g_1(z-vt)
\\&=-{1\over v}E_y
\end{align}
$$